# MySQL Update will only update some fields specified in the query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a very simple query which updates a 'status', a 'has_note', (both are `tinyint`s in the database) and a time. The time updates correctly every time this is run, however, the other two are not affected and never changed.

Here is the code:

```
$status_sql = "
   UPDATE voe_employment 
   SET status = 5, email_date = NOW() 
   WHERE emp_id = " . $_POST['emp_id'] . " 
   LIMIT 1";

$status_result = mysql_query($status_sql);
```

I have copied and pasted the resulting `$status_sql` into `pmadmin`, and everything updates correctly.

Also, `$status_result = 1` after executing this code, which signifies success.

This block of code is wrapped around a "try, catch" statement, and the catch is never run/activated. And I have tried wrapping the table name in ``, wrapping the 5 in '', etc.

Comment: Assuming `emp_id` is the primary (or at least a unique) key, you shouldn't need the `LIMIT 1`. If it isn't a unique identifier, why the limit?

Comment: Your right its just how I like to code I guess. I took it out anyway but no change.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure it wasn't important and didn't imply something unusual about the structure. Everybody has their own "defensive coding" styles/paranoia. I can't think of anything to add other than the field `has_note` you initially mentioned is nowhere in the supplied query.

Comment: I noticed that, I had taken 'has_note' out of the code I was testing and forgot. I figured to make my point i'd mention it in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to make sure no other code is doing another `UPDATE` right after.  We have found this in the past.  Another unexpected update was running that we didn't know was that overwrote the data.